# Calling a method inside a if condition - React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

Before rendering a component I need to check if the user has been authenticated. If not, the user will be redirected to the login page.

I created a separate file with a class called auth to handle authentications.

But each time I'm getting redirected to the login page even when the user is authenticated.

**In protectedRout it jumps into the else part without waiting to auth.checkLogin()**

*I'm a newbie please help me out.*

```
import React from 'react'
import auth from './authState'

function ProtectedRoute({component: Component, ...rest} ) {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props)  => {
            if(auth.checkLogin() === true){
                console.log("rendering the component")
                return <Component/>
            }else{
                console.log("fail rendering")
                return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login' , state: {from:props.location}}} />
            }
        }} />
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

in ./authState

```
class Auth {

    constructor(){
        this.isLoggedIn = false
    }

    checkLogin = async () => {
        if(this.isLoggedIn === true){
            console.log('already logged')
            this.isLoggedIn = true
            return this.isLoggedIn
        }else{
            await axios.get('/checkloggedin')
            .then(res => {
                console.log("server check result" + res.data.authenticated)
                if(res.data.authenticated === true){
                  this.isLoggedIn = true
                  return this.isLoggedIn
                }else{
                    this.isLoggedIn = false
                    return this.isLoggedIn
                }
            })
        }
        
    }

    logOut = async () =>{
        await axios.get('logout')
        .then(res => {
            if(res.data.loggingOut === true){
                this.isLoggedIn = false
            }else{

            }
        })
    }

    setLog = () =>{
        console.log('setLog called')
        this.isLoggedIn = true
    }

    setLogOut = () =>{
        console.log('setting logout')
        this.logOut()
        return this.isLoggedIn
    }
}

export default new Auth()
```

Comment: You've got some logging in there.  What's the output?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess the issue is in this line: `if(res.data.authenticated === true){`.  Add `console.log(res.data.authenticated)` and `console.log(typeof res.data.authenticated)` and let us know what it says.  I suspect the result isn't `=== true`.  Maybe it's the string "true", which is not the same as boolean true.

Comment: Oh wait, the issue is in `if(auth.checkLogin() === true)`.  `checkLogin` is returning a promise, not a boolean, because the method is `async`

Comment: Thank you. I called the async part inside the protectedRoute and used a state to rerender the component when it get the response. It's working fine now.